# Encoder for odometry (Wheel vs motor)

Tags: odometry, quadrature-encoder

Hey i am building a ROS enabled robot which relies on Odometry data from encoders for the purpose of SLAM .

I am confused between what would be more accurate in estimating the pose and robot position either using encoders mounter directly to the back of the motor shaft vs quadrature encoders attached to the wheel .

PS:- I have a Ebike motor running my bot , so as you can guess it uses chain drive to turn the wheels . Please suggest me some mechanical designs by which i can attach encoders to a chain drive .

Answer (score 2):

Since it's the wheels which change the robot's pose in the environment, I'd suggest putting the encoders to the wheels. Especially if the motor and the wheel are only connected by a chain, introducing possible slack between motor and wheel angular positions. Would the wheel sit directly on the motor axis, it would not matter.